# ERROR! This JHipster subgenerator is not intented for standalone use

Tags: jhipster, yo

I'm trying to scaffold monolith application with the help of [jHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech). I get this error right after selecting application name. Log:

```
Welcome to JHipster v5.6.1

WARNING! Your Node version is not LTS (Long Term Support), use it at your own risk! JHipster does not support non-LTS releases, so if you encounter a bug, please use a LTS version first.
? Which *type* of application would you like to create? (Use arrow keys)
? Which *type* of application would you like to create? Monolithic application (
recommended for simple projects)
? What is the base name of your application? (jhipster)
? What is the base name of your application? jhipster
Error jhipster

ERROR! This JHipster subgenerator is not intented for standalone use.
```

Comment: This error is a validation introduced recently (see [PR](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/8623/files/fcab41313d1cf34255a1ecba4d9c68586b5e3e6e)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you call jhipster generator using yeoman command: `yo jhipster`. This syntax is deprecated. Please use the JHipster CLI:

```
jhipster
```

In general, run `jhipster <command>` instead of `yo jhipster:<command>`.